# nodejs array returning empty. async question

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, fetch

I want to make n amount of api calls and add the all the results to an array. Then return the array.

n = length of word array

It is returning an empty result. I know it's an async function but for the life of me I can't figure out a solution, any help would be appreciated.

```
app.get('/api/', async (req, res) => {
    let wordArray = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]

    let resultArray = []

    for (let i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
        fetch('apiurl' + new URLSearchParams({
            word: wordArray[i],
        }))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                resultArray.push(responseData);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    console.log(resultArray);
});
```

Comment: Put the promises in an array, use `Promise.all()` to get all the results, then sum that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using async call, then you console.log resultArray, after that async call is executed. You should wrap everything in promise.all

```
const wordArray = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]

let resultArray = [];

let actions = [];
for (let i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
  const action = fetch('apiurl' + new URLSearchParams({
    word: wordArray[i],
  }))
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        resultArray.push(responseData);
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error) });
  
  actions.push(action);
}

Promise.all(actions).then(() => {
  console.log(resultArray);
});
```